# Free and paid Reverse Geocoding Services for an app that polls frequently

Tags: iphone, ios4, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'm in the planning stages of an App and It needs to poll someones location frequently. Depending on your location the app will be affected. I don't need to store this data only use it real time.

There are free services I can use, but a lot of them have usage limits I feel I would meet quickly with this kind of app. I could add a check in feature so I am not polling as much but I would like it to be seamless. Edit- I also don't need to display a map I just need to know the location.

What are some good services I could use?

If my app does well I could move to a paid one if my app needs it but it couldn't be very expensive since I'm a single dev. So please list paid ones too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not understand exactly what you have to do. 
If you have to reverse Geocode a precise coordinate the iOS SDK have this feature built in.

in iOS previous then 5.0 you can use the MKReverseGeocoder coupled with the MKReverseGeocoderDelegate methods that returns to you an MKPlacemark. This object is not very useful because does not have enough information.

Starting from iOS 5.0 you could use the very powerful CLGeocoder object to retrieve a CLPlacemark array. This object store a lot of informations.

You could read the [official apple documentation of CLGeocoder here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009573)

Comment: This is exactly what I need I think , one question though is CL come from google like mapkit? Or is from apple? And are there any limitations? I tried looking at the page but it just says don't request more than a minute.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Other places I looked always suggested services that required me to use a map or had very limited number of times you could make this request for your app. I just need to request someones location periodically to use the data real time.

Comment: CL prefix stands for CoreLocation. In order to use it you need to link the CoreLocation Framework to your project and the you must #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> where you need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Geocoda](http://geocoda.com) as well.  It's got global geocode data and is free for developer sized accounts and reasonably-priced for any production scenario.  Disclaimer: I work at Geocoda.

Answer (score 0):

MapBox provides everything you need to design and integrate gorgeous maps into your web and mobile applications.

http://mapbox.com/foursquare/

Comment: I edited my question I don't need to display a map, just need to know the users location. Content changes based on where the user is.

Comment: They have geocoding API also. You can use standard map and their API